# How can I change the font in the "edit data" window in pgAdmin III?

Tags: pgadmin

I wonder whether I can change the font in the "edit data" window in pgAdmin III.  I use  Windows 7 and OS X 10.10.

Comment: have you seen [this](http://www.pgadmin.org/support/faq.php#FontProblem1) ?  Also, what O/S are you using?

Comment: @MaxVernon Thanks, I am on Windows 7 and OS X 10.10. I guess I just have to change the system font then. Not ideal, but better than impossible.

Comment: Sounds like that's what they are saying.  If that works, post it as an answer so future visitors will know what to do.

Comment: @MaxVernon I tried, it didn't work :(